# Can JavaScript handle C structures?

Tags: javascript, c, stm32

I'm setting up an embedded Web Server on `STM32F4 MCU`. The exchange of data between the Web Server and software variables is possible through CGI functions.

**Example :**

https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/Network/html/group__ws__script__langugage.html

I want to send large variables from the `STM32` program, and process data with `JavaScript` client-side.

```
typedef struct
{
    SEventContext EventContext;
    UValuesPids Pids;
    UEventContextTemperatureInputs RawTemperatures;
    UBooleans Booleans;      
    UVariousData Various;   
    SNetworkOutputs NetworkOutputs;
    float BoardTemperature;
    SCounters Counters;
    SProductionTestData ProductionTestData;
} SAcquisition;
```

Is it possible for JavaScript to process large variables ? Or the alternative is to send each element of my structure one by one ?

Comment: What is #C? Do you mean C#? Or is it just a typo and you really mean just plain C?

Comment: And the ability for a "client" to be able to handle what you send to it, depends on *how* you send it, and *what* you send.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That seems to be "hashtag C" - the way kids speak nowadays.

Comment: Plain C.
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/Network/html/group__ws__cgi__script.html#ga5203e3a1a0f95a8b76fb83bec73e4be8

Comment: The idea is to use the netCGI_Script to send my structure

Comment: Yes, you can even use C in Javascript, using Web Assempbly, or asm.js.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But the best thing would be to wrap your data inside JSON. An example for a working JSON library would be [parson](https://github.com/kgabis/parson).

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) is the way to go in order to pass massive data to/from javascript, a library might be useful but isn't really needed, JSON is a text file with simple enough format.

Comment: All true, but a pointer to a library can be really useful. (also it doesn't need to be a file but that is me being really pedantic)